# How to stop Dagger2 from generating MemberInjectors that have been removed

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I've removed a class from my `Injector` interface.

```
interface Injector : XdkUiComponent {

    //fun inject(target: RegistrationViewModel)
```

the class itself `RegistrationViewModel`has been deleted as well.  yet when I build I get the following error, 
`symbol:   class RegistrationViewModel
  location: class RegistrationViewModel_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\devDebug\com\company\android\sales\universal\auth\viewmodel\RegistrationViewModel_MembersInjector.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
      RegistrationViewModel instance, RegistrationService registrationApi) {
                                      ^`

I've tried invalidating the cache and restarting, as well as clean/rebuild.  I even deleted all files under the `generated` folder,  All to no avail.  I still get the same error.

This error started after I switched branches.

Comment: You can try deleting the gradle build cache files in `{HOME}/.gradle/caches/build-cache-*`

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Odd it seems I don't have that folder.  Under `.gradle/` I have `5.2.1`, `5.3.1`, `5.4`, `buildOutputCleanup` and `vcs-1`  None of which have a caches file in them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227172/how-to-stop-dagger2-from-generating-memberinjectors-that-have-been-removed#comment99076188_56227172) is right but you are looking in the wrong place. It seems you are looking in the gradle file of your proyect not the hidden one inside your `{HOME}` directory.

To see the hidden files in finder use `command + shift + .`